# what am i doing wrong as my code is not giving expected results

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Question
displayCartTotal, use the formatAsMoney function to set appState.billFormated to the formatted total bill. The already assigned appState.bill and appState.country should come be handy now!

Set the text content of the data-bill SPAN to the formatted bill set in appState.billFormated

Finally, call uiCanInteract to wrap up displayCartTotal.

!!

my code

```
> Blockquote

const formatAsMoney = (amount, buyerCountry) => {
        const country = countries.find(c => c.country === buyerCountry);
        const {code, currency} = country;
        if (code && currency) return amount.toLocaleString(code, {style: "currency", currency});
        return amount.toLocaleString("en-us", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"});
        };  
      const detectCardType = ({target}) => {

      }

      const validateCardExpiryDate = ({target}) => {

      };      
      const validateCardHolderName = ({target}) => {

      };

      const uiCanInteract = () => {

      };

      const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => {
        const {results} = results; 
        const [data] = results;
        const {itemsInCart, buyerCountry} = data;
        appState.items = itemsInCart;
        appState.country = buyerCountry;
        appState.bill = itemsInCart.reduce((result, item,) => result = item.price *                 item.qty, 0);
        appState.billFormated = formatAsMoney (appState.bill, appState.country);
        databill.textContent = appstate.billFormated;
        uiCanInteract();

      };
```

want pointers to how to effectively solve the above posted question please!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask good questions :)

Comment: Some notes: What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen? Then, remove all the code that doesn't change the result, until you're left with the minimal amount of code that still should do something you want it to do, but for some reason doesn't. Also, it's certainly easier for us to help you if we can test the code ourself.

Comment: For starters we don't know what expected results are for this code or what the input data is. There are also undefined functions being used. Provide a proper explanation for what it should do, what it is doing different than expected, show what expected results are based on sample input

Comment: this seems like it might not be intentional:
`const {results} = results;` you already destructured {result} from the first argument  in displayCartTotal is the expected input: `{results: {results: { data } }` if so consider renaming this. Also I'm skeptical if results being defined 2x in the same method will work. `{ results: otherName}` seems safer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you meant

```
const displayCartTotal = (resultingStuff) => {
        const {results} = resultingStuff; 
        const [data] = results;
        const {itemsInCart, buyerCountry} = data;
        appState.items = itemsInCart;
        appState.country = buyerCountry;
        appState.bill = itemsInCart.reduce((result, item,) => result = item.price *                 item.qty, 0);
        appState.billFormated = formatAsMoney (appState.bill, appState.country);
        databill.textContent = appstate.billFormated;
        uiCanInteract();

      };
```

```js
const blah = ({result}) => {
  const {result} = result
  document.write(result)
}
blah({result: { result: 'apple' } })

/*
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Cannot declare a lexical variable twice: 'result'.
*/
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Cannot declare a lexical variable twice: 'result'.
You have defined results 2x in the same lexical scope and JavaScript (nor anyone reading this) have any idea which results you refer to.

Note that in general: it is unwise to use such vague variable names as `results` and `data` what type of data? what types of `results` this will also help you from accidentally naming the parameter the same as one of variables that you attempted to assign:

Note that:

```
const displayCartTotal = ({results}) =>
```

Is equivalent to:

```
const displayCartTotal = (stuff) => {
const results = stuff.results
```

meaning you already assigned results... also are you sure that the object really has `results` in it twice?

because here is what your code did:

```
const displayCartTotal = (stuff) => {
const results = stuff.results
const results = results.results // UNHAPPY: cannot declare lexical variable twice
```

If the api really replies with:

```
{
"results": {
  "results": {
    "data": []
  }
}
```

then your best bet is to do:

```
const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => {
const { results: innerResults } = results
const { data } = innerResults
```

or you can do the above in one line:

```
const displayCartTotal = ({results: { results: { data } }) => {
// Now only data will be defined but it looks like that's all you need.
```

Comment: this has been helpfull very much grateful.